# Taking the limit of an integral with a constant

Tags: integration

I have a simple question, but it causes some problems.

I want to find: $$\lim_{a \to \infty} \int^\infty_a  a \hspace{1mm} dF(x)$$

Where $a$ is constant.

I think this will go to: $$ \infty  \int^\infty_\infty dF(x) = 0$$

Is this true? I know the integral is equal to zero, but I am confused about the term outside? Maybe it does not make sense.

Thank you.

Comment: what is $F(x)$ here

Comment: It is the distribution function.

Comment: The limit need not be $0$ even when $F$ is a probability distribution function.

Answer (score 0):

If $1<a<2$ and $F$ has  a density function of the type $\frac c {x^{a}}$ for $x >1$ then the limit is $\infty$.